# owl carousel won't load image and a button

Tags: javascript, angular, web, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel in my angular app, I'm sending an API request to get the items and display them in the page using owl carousel.

I'm showing the items in bootstrap cards and it was working perfectly but once I set loop to true the images in the card are not being loaded, even though I already got a response and I can see all my items in the console but when I scroll between the items in the carousel it's like there is lazy loading and the images takes times to show up.

html file

```
<owl-carousel  [options]="myCarouselOptions" [items]="myList">
<app-info-card class="item" *ngFor="let item of myList" [item]="item"></app-info-card>  
 </owl-carousel>
```

info card file

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" *ngIf="">
     // this is the image that it disappers when scrolling and redisplays after a while 
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="open()">
      <img (click)="open()" class="card-img-top" [src]="item.image" Onerror="this.src=''" alt="No image">
    </a>
   
  </div>
```

ts file

```
myCarouselOptions = {
    items: 3,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 30000000,
    autoplayHoverPause: false,
    responsiveClass: true,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    rtl: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: false,
        dots: true,
      },}}


 ngOnInit() {
    this.getmyList();
  }

  check() {
   this.subscriptions.sink = this.itemsService
      .getList()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response) {
          this.myList = response.data;
        }


      });
  }
```

i noticed that I'm displying 6 items but the owl carousel creates 12 items , 6 items with cloned class

[image]

Comment: add this to stackblitz

Comment: it's not going to show the problem as the image will load perfectly if it's static URL but it will take time to show up if I'm using get API